# Explicación de una frase compleja

Tags: gramática, expresiones, coloquialismos

He pensado intensamente en la frase siguiente. Comprendo más o menos lo que significa, pero no su estructura gramatical:

> Cuando les dijeron que les tocaba hacer un desalojo, habrán pensado: "Mierda, qué desagradable", ¿no?

Me parece que hay tres sujetos mencionado en esta frase: De primero un sujeto significado de "les", de segundo un de "dijeron" y "habrán pensado" y finalmente un de "tocaba". ¿Es correcto? La frase a mi me parece muy compleja.

Comment: Moritz, thanks for the interesting question.  I want to reassure you that it's okay to ask in English.  And for a complex question like this, it might in fact be clearer if you ask in English.  That would make me feel more certain that I'm understanding accurately what you are asking, and the way you're interpreting the sentence. If you want to edit your question, you can click where it says "edit" right below the tags ("gramática", "expresiones", "coloquialismos").

Comment: Esta frase se puede traducir con la misma estructura al inglés. Así que no entiendo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, es compleja, pero los hispanohablantes utilizamos frases como esa, a menudo.

La dificultad es que los pronombres están omitidos. Voy a inventarme los sujetos, para que sea más fácil:

> Cuando [unos] les dijeron [a ellos] que (a ellos) les tocaba hacer un desalojo.

---

Así es más fácil. Ahora vamos a analizar la frase, por partes.

Empezamos con una frase sencilla:

> Unos les dijeron eso (a ellos).

Esta frase es parte de una oración más compleja.

> Cuando unos les dijeron eso (a ellos).

Finalmente, reemplazamos "eso" por una subordinada sustantiva:

> Cuando unos les dijeron (a ellos) que *blablabla*

---

Así que solamente intervienen dos grupos de personas: "unos" y "ellos".

Pero estos grupos de personas no son sujetos. En la oración principal, el sujeto es "Unos". Sin embargo, en la subordinada sustantiva, el sujeto es "hacer un desalojo". `"Hacer un desalojo" les tocaba a ellos`.

Espero haber ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es espacialmente interesante y el análisis es complejo. A riesgo de quedarme corto, puedo decir que pero se trata de una oración subordinada; una conjetura en antefuturo que, a su vez, es subordinada a la primera y dos interjecciones

**Oracion circunstancial subordinada advervial**

Introducida por *"cuando"* que funciona como una conjunción.

> Cuando les dijeron que les tocaba hacer un desalojo, habrán pensado "mierda, qué desagradable".

**Oración subordinada sustantiva transitiva (proposición subordinada adverbial)**

> [estos] les dijeron [a aquellos] que les tocaba hacer un desalojo.

**Conjetura en antefuturo (predicado de la oración circunstancial)**

> [Aquellos] habrán pensado
>
> "Mierda, qué desagradable" (Interjección que funciona como objeto directo)

**Interjección**

> ¿no?

---

A pesar de que la pregunta busca solamente la explicación la estructura gramatical, es interesante desmenuzar el contexto de la narración del cual obtenemos cuatro actores directos:

**Narrador:** Existe solo uno que introduce el contexto para hacer una referencia literal a un supuesto comentario de otro sujeto (en este caso *aquellos*).

**Escucha:** Existe tambien uno, quien recibe el mensaje del narrador.

**Estos:** Los que informaron a *aquellos* que les tocaba hacer un desalojo.

**Aquellos:** Los encargados de ejecutar el desalojo.

> Cuando [estos] les dijeron [a aquellos] que les tocaba hacer un desalojo, [aqellos] habrán pensado: *(Narracion)*
>
> "Mierda, qué desagradable",      *(Referencia al supuesto comentario [de aquellos])*
>
> ¿no? *(Interjección del narrador)*

Answer (score 0):

No voy a repetir lo que ya está explicado en las respuestas anteriores a la mia, asi que me voy a centrar en hacerte ver que hasta las frases mas complejas no son mas que frases simples "con florituras".

Tenemos la siguiente oración:

> Cuando les dijeron que les tocaba hacer un desalojo, habrán pensado: "Mierda, qué desagradable", ¿no?

Lo primero es separar la oración de la interjección "¿no?", ya que lo único que está haciendo es matizar el sentido de la misma, es decir, convierte una afirmación en una duda.

Después pasa una cosa curiosa, y es que si añadimos los sujetos omitidos y reorganizamos los elementos de la oración la podemos pasar a algo mas sencillo de entender y analizar:

> [Ellos] habrán pensado: "Mierda, qué desagradable" cuando les dijeron que les tocaba hacer un desalojo.

Ahora vamos a pasar a sustituir esas florituras por elementos sencillos:

> [Ellos] habrán pensado (algo) cuando (otra cosa)

Esto puede parecer una sobresimplificación, pero de repente vemos una oración muy básica:

`[ Ellos ] habrán pensado (algo) cuando (otra cosa)
 sujeto  |              Predicado
          [    Verbo   ][ C.D ] [Complemento Circunstancial]`

Pero claro, hemos omitido un montón de información en este análisis, en concreto hemos eliminado por completo la subordinada, esta la podemos analizar por separado tal que asi:

> Les dijeron que les tocaba hacer un desalojo.

La razón por la que todo parece tan complejo es porque la subordinada contiene otra subordinada!

> Les dijeron (algo)

Aqui es bastante sencillo, "Les" es CI, dijeron el verbo y la subordinada hace de CD.

Continuamos con la siguiente:

> les tocaba hacer un desalojo.
>   Aqui "un desalojo" hace de CD, "les" de CI y encima esta oración es impersonal.

## Conclusión

es una oración bastante compleja, que implementa prácticamente todas las complicaciones posibles, espero que esta respuesta te sirva para analizar en el futuro, ¡divide y vencerás!